# problem with "ReferenceError: fs is not defined"

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord.js, bots

so ive been trying to fix this problem for the past hour and can get it to work, its probably a stupid mistake, but what you see here is my fs.readdir is defined.

[vsc error + code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xnUj.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import fs. Put this above line 25 or your first use of `fs`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still don't install the `fs` package, go to terminal then type `npm install fs`

1. Click on Terminal
2. On your keyboard command `Ctrl + C` if your  bot is running
3. type `npm install fs` or `npm i fs`
4. On your code now type `const fs = require('fs');`

You can put it on line 13 in your `js file`